# neo4j.rb v7 compatibility with attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby, neo4j

Just upgraded from neo4j.rb v4 to neo4j.rb v7 and found that

```
require 'attr_encrypted' # v3.0.1

class PmConfiguration

  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :do_api_token   
  property :ql_pub_key   
  property :ql_email     
  property :cc_email   
  property :default_dev_domain   
  property :login 
  property :secret_sudo_pwd 

  attr_encrypted :sudo_pwd, key: 'ql', prefix: 'secret_', encode: true

  class << self    ...
```

produces:

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `attr_encrypted' for #<Class:0x005566a6b5bf00>
Did you mean?  attr_reader
```

when the class is run. Worked fine with neo4j.rb v4.

Is there a work around or a neo4j way of doing the same/similar thing which I haven't yet found?

Regards

Comment: I've just tried a fresh Rails app and I get that error with 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 6.0, and 7.0...  When it's working for you, what versions of the `neo4j` and `neo4j-core` gems are you using?

Comment: After reading a lot of code, the issue is the difference between attr_encrypted 1.3 & 3.0.

With v 3.0 it is necessary to add an additional column (if persistence is required).
In the example above, I added:
property :secret_sudo_pwd_iv
Not sure about rails because my set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followup:
After reading a lot of code, the issue is the difference between attr_encrypted 1.3 & 3.0.

With v 3.0 it is necessary to add an additional column (if persistence is required).

In the example above, I added:

```
property :secret_sudo_pwd_iv
```

Not sure about rails because my set up was more PORO, so I also had to `extend AttrEncrypted` within the class.

As it happens, this is all fairly well documented in the README.
Sorry to have been somewhat premature in the posting.

Hope this helps.

The revised model is below (which works with attr_encrypted v3.0)

```
class PmConfiguration 

  extend AttrEncrypted

  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :do_api_token
  property :ql_pub_key
  property :ql_email
  property :cc_email
  property :default_dev_domain
  property :login
  property :secret_sudo_pwd
  property :secret_sudo_pwd_iv
```

Comment: Glad that you were able to figure it out.  Thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Add  the attr_encypted gem

or

```
gem install attr_encrypted
```

or in your gemfile

```
gem "attr_encrypted", "~> 3.0.0"
```

Comment: by way of clarification, the gem was part of the bundle. worked fine for neo4j.rb v4, but does not for neo4j.rb v7